# When exporting from Keynote to Html, some animations (flip and orbital) don't work

Tags: keynote, bug, html

I'm using Keynote 09 (version 5.1.1) and the latest Safari. Is there a way to make the "flip" and "orbital" show up in the html slides? (During the export process they were changed to "dissolve").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most 'advanced' animations don't work in the exported HTML presentations from Keynote '09. This is a known limitation of the software and does not appear to be a bug<sup>1</sup> since the animations are replaced with the Dissolve animation.

Keynote 6 has much better HTML export using iCloud with support for most of the animations in the latest browsers. If you need such animations, consider updating to Keynote 6 or use Keynote for iCloud.

[image]

> Choose beautifully designed slide transitions ranging from smooth fades to elaborate animations so engaging you may forget you’re working in your browser.

<sup><sup>1</sup> I'm sure I remember reading somewhere a list of animations which weren't supported in HTML exports from Keynote '09, but I can't find it now.</sup>